# Automatically adjust left column width in paracol (or minipage, tabularx, etc.) to fit unwrapped text

Tags: columns, width, paracol

I'm pretty new to LaTeX.  In the MWE, I need the header and extra info text to never wrap.  I need the small details to wrap, as needed, while utilizing the maximum space.  I think everything should work as intended IF the left column width would be automatically set to the unwrapped text contents width.

The actual text will be generated periodically by a python script, so I need this to work without manual intervention, if possible.  And also work with normal sectioning in the TOC, etc.

I am not married to paracol, but I've gotten closer to the needed results than with other solutions  I've tried (e.g., tabularx, etc.).  Some of the solutions I've found online seem to work *until* I include the \section and then break.

I feel like this should be easier than I'm making it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
    % set 3.9in automatically, rather than manually
    \setcolumnwidth{3.9in, \fill}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section{Header That Goes Here (Longer)}
    
        {\bfseries\large Extra info Goes Here}
        \switchcolumn
        \raggedleft
        {\footnotesize Small details go here}
    \end{paracol}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
    % set 4.6in automatically, rather than manually
    \setcolumnwidth{4.6in, \fill}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section{Header That Goes Here}
        
        {\bfseries\large Extra info Goes Here (Sometimes is a bit longer)}
        \switchcolumn
        \raggedleft
        {\footnotesize Small details go here}
    \end{paracol}
    
    \clearpage
    
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
    % set 3.9in automatically, rather than manually
    \setcolumnwidth{3.9in, \fill}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section{Header That Goes Here (Longer)}
        
        {\bfseries\large Extra info Goes Here}
        \switchcolumn
        \raggedleft
        {\footnotesize Small details go here, and these are sometimes longer}
    \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use tabularx, but your left hand text is very long not to wrap...

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\zsec[3]{%
\par
\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l|>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}%
\large\sffamily\bfseries\refstepcounter{section}\thesection. #1&\\[5pt]
\mbox{\bfseries\large#2}&\footnotesize \vspace*{-30pt} #3\end{tabularx}\par}


\begin{document}


\zsec
{Header That Goes Here (Longer)}
{Extra info Goes Here}
{Small details go here}

\zsec
{Header That Goes Here}
{Extra info Goes Here (Sometimes is a bit longer)}
{Small details go here}
    
\zsec
{Header That Goes Here (Longer)}
{Extra info Goes Here}
{Small details go here, and these are sometimes longer}

\end{document}
```